# Xamarin Deploy on iPhone not working with Xcode 14

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It's not possible to deploy any Xamarin iOS app on a physical device. Maybe someone of you already had the same issues and knows about a work around?

Xcode: Version 14.0 (14A309)
Visual Studio for Mac: 17.3.4 (build 4)

When trying to Debug I get following error. I've already tried multiple times to clean the project and delete bin and obj folders:

```
Target _CopyAppConfigFile:
  Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    Xamarin.iOS -> .../Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/Xamarin.iOS.exe
Target _CopyResourcesToBundle:
  Skipping target "_CopyResourcesToBundle" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _WriteAppManifest:
  Skipping target "_WriteAppManifest" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileToNative:
    /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone14.2-16.0/response-file.rsp 
    Xamarin.iOS 15.12.0.2 (d17-3: 87f98a75e) using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk
    Compilation failed with code 1, command:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Wno-receiver-forward-class -Wno-objc-missing-super-calls -Wno-unguarded-availability-new -stdlib=libc++ -gdwarf-2 -std=c++14 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/15.12.0.2/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -arch arm64 -c -o /Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone14.2-16.0/mtouch-cache/arm64/registrar.o -x objective-c++ -D DEBUG /Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone14.2-16.0/mtouch-cache/registrar.m
    In file included from /Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone14.2-16.0/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:3:
    /Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone14.2-16.0/mtouch-cache/registrar.h:112:9: fatal error: 'CHIP/CHIP.h' file not found
    #import <CHIP/CHIP.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    MTOUCH : error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/new
Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "Xamarin.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

When trying to Deploy a release build I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mlaunch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --installdev ".../Xamarin.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/Xamarin.iOS.app" --device ios "--devname=iPhone 13 Pro" --install-progress
error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation' (path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation): 
dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation, 0x0001): Library not loaded: '@rpath/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery'
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/15.12.0.2/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/15.12.0.2/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file)
        

Application could not be uploaded to the device.
```

Comment: XCode 14 / iOS 16 support has not been released yet.  You can try switching to the Preview channel if you want to test the previews

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How do I activate the preview channel on Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: in the update dialog, switch the channel dropdown

Comment: @Jason there is no switching to preview channel in VS2022. You need to install VS2022 Preview. But it doesn't have anything new regarding that at the moment either.

Comment: You can follow this GH issue for more info: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954

Comment: Is Xamarin still alive?!

Comment: This does not work in Preview either, and is an active issue in MAUI development that I am experiencing now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downgrading the Command Line Tools to 13.4 helped me.

In xCode (still 14) -> Preferences -> Location -> Command Line Tools, select version 13.4 instead of 14. Restart tools and it worked again...

[image]

Hope it works for you too!

Comment: How do I downgrade the Command Line Tools? I only have version 14 to choose from in Xcode

Comment: @Drake open https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ and look for Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.4

Comment: After download and install the command line tools. Xcode does not show me the option for Xcode 13.4. Any idea?

Comment: I am in the same boat as Huy.Vu.  How do we get 13.4 to show up in the Command Line Tools once it is installed?

Comment: Same scenario as outlined in two comments above, even though the Software Update Manager suggests I need to upgrade (again) to 14.0. Is there a workaround for this yet?

Comment: Downgrading to 13.4.1 solved my issue.

Comment: If you don't see 13.1 version, you should download and install this one https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.4.1/Xcode_13.4.1.xip

Comment: I can't downgrade using Ventura

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to downgrade to a previous version of XCode (e.g. https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.4.1/Xcode_13.4.1.xip if logged in as developer)

Here you can select the XCode version you want: https://developer.apple.com/download/all

You can have multiple XCode version installed side by side. Use `sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/XCode.app` to switch between them.

Comment: Thanks CoffeeCode ! I was able to select the former version of XCode Command Line Tools after I installed it from your link.

Comment: This should be the accepted workaround as installing only the Command Line Tools is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue. I've update the xcode to 14 and visual studio (from windows) stopped working with the xamarin.ios debug/build. I needed to downgrade the xcode to the previous version to get it working back.

Comment: I also  end up with same situation, and searching for solution before downgrade xcode

Answer (score 1):

Apple released Xcode 14 overnight, which auto-updated on my machine, so it is now officially the version to use, but still no support for building Xamarin apps with VS Mac Preview. :(

Comment: Its quite concerning that this is not tested against Xcode 14.0 beta in the VS (Mac) Preview channel, in anticipation for public release. Always playing catch-up.

Answer (score 1):

After installing command-line manually, command-line tools is empty, after selecting XCode 14.0.1 itself resolved the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the latest update from Xamarin.iOS the issue is resolved. I am running 14.0.1 XCODE,
17.3.6 Visual studio 2022 community
16.0.0.72 Xamarin.iOS
I am able to deploy the solution to both older(15.5) and newer(16.0) simulator
So the issue is resolved, please update all the relevant tools. Note I have also checked deployment from Rider IDE.

Comment: The current SDK has issued with the current version of Xcode 14.2 and fails to deploy to physical devices running tvOS 16.1.