# Visual Studio error HE0004 Could not load the framework 'DVTItunesSoftwareServiceFoundation'

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.28 on windows that is paired to a MacBook and I am trying to deploy an IOS application to an ipad. Every time I launch to the ipad, I run into error HE0004 . I see others with a similar but not exact issue. Seems it's related with 'ContentDeliveryServices' but I'm not sure if it's the same issue I'm having.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation' (path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework/DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation):          0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWmho.png)

I updated Visual studio and Xamarin, and Xcode on the MacBook but I am still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try to update the Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.28 to the Visual Studio 2022. The visual studio 2019 is too old.

And according to this case [which has the same error message as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73704829/xamarin-deploy-on-iphone-not-working-with-xcode-14), the **Visual Studio for Mac: 17.3.4 (build 4)** and the **XCode 13.4** work together will resolve this problem.

In addition, you can check the official document about the [[META] Xcode 14.3 Support for Xamarin, .NET 6/7 and MAUI](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561).